# How to set up pgadmin4 with nginx in ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: nginx, postgresql

I installed pgadmin4 in my ubuntu server with SERVER_MODE = True.

I have nginx as the web server handling all the request. How do I set up nginx to serve pgadmin4?

Also How do I create pgadmin4 to start automatically when the server start?

Comment: Any heads up on this bro ?

Comment: thanks for the help. I use nginx + gunicron. will give it a try.

Answer (score 3):

You've really only got a handful of options here.

(1) Use `nginx` and a backend that runs the `pgAdmin4.py` Python file.  Whether this is Unicorn, or `uwsgi` launched, and you `proxy_pass` or similar to the backend in `nginx` is up to you, however this is one option.

(2) Launch `pgAdmin4.py` (doesn't matter if it's `SERVER_MODE = True` or `SERVER_MODE = False`), run it on the standard `localhost:5050` port, and then set up `nginx` to `proxy_pass` all requests to the configured domain/hostname to pass off to the backend, with:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5050;
}
```

... or similar.

Beyond that there's not really much you can do otherwise to get `pgAdmin4.py` to work with `nginx`.  (I use the second of these options on my laptop, with a customized configuration and pgAdmin4 launched as a dedicated system user)